# how to view the lists of AWS Lambda functions which you're authorised

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have more than 100 lambda functions and they are accessible, readable and executable based on your department. Saying, I can just see the lambda function name on the screen but If I want to read any of them, I get permission denied if I don't fall in the right department. So, I'm wondering if, there are some ways that list out only the functions where I'm allowed to? Because it's a mess.

Comment: Worth checking aws cli  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/list-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

The `ListFunctions` command returns *all* functions.

It could actually be quite challenging to determine which functions a user is entitled to view/list/execute since the information could be in multiple policies.

You could call the IAM Policy Simulator [`simulate-custom-policy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/simulate-custom-policy.html) command to determine whether a particular call to a specific function would work, but that would be a lot of work just for a listing of functions.